# DVD+RW writing occasionally fails

Tags: dvd

**EDIT: The issue has slowly and steadily gone away with much, much reading and writing through the night... Not sure what it is that's been fixed, if you're reading this and you're having the same issue I suggest looking at the first 2 posts by ChanganAuto and DavidPostill. I'm going to have to guess that it was a dirty write head, and it slowly fixed itself. I'll have to look into a cleaning disk later.**

When writing data to the disk, at a random point it pops up with this error:

> This DVD-ROM drive is read-only. You can copy files to this writable
> DVD, but you must insert it into a writable drive.

[Drive can supposedly write to DVD+RW disks](https://www.asus.com/us/motherboards-components/optical-drives/internal-dvd-drive/drw24f1st/techspec/)

After error, files appear as "ready to be written to disk". When trying to write something else to it, it says it's full. Windows explorer says that it has 4 gigs free. Formatting lets me use it again until the error occurs again. Sometimes writing works fine, I've been able to fill the disk a couple times. Doesn't seem to be a pattern to what's causing it to fail.

Disk is new, not scratched or damaged, hasn't been exposed to sunlight

What is causing this? Other people mentioned either the writing process being interrupted or the drive being incompatible, neither seem to be an issue, am I wrong?

Disk: Verbatim 4x DVD+RW

Drive: ASUS DRW-24F1ST

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Have you cleaned the drive write head lens?

Comment: Intermittent failures like this one are the hardest to troubleshoot. It could be due to many different causes, even a combination of two or more: Bugs in the undisclosed software you're using, defective hardware like a laser on the verge of total failure, mechanical problems in the drive (many parts), optical problems (may require cleaning as commented above), "compatibility" issues (some drives simply "don't like" certain disks), etc., etc.

Comment: And you say "disk is new" but a 4x is more likely to be "new old stock" so natural degradation should be considered as well...

Comment: @DavidPostill Not sure that's the issue. The drive has always played nice with CDs. Guess their tech is less "precise" tho. Will try soon, but I'd like taking the thing apart to be the last resort.

Comment: You don't have to take it apart - search for CD writer cleaning disk.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Using file explorer to transfer files to/from the disk.

Comment: Trying a different software is the next logical step then. Windows native tools should work and they do until they don't. Also keep in mind that reading and writing are different tasks and CDs and DVDs are read and written by 2 different lasers. That it reads doesn't means it writes and that it does correctly one and/or the other for one type of media doesn't mean it'll do the same for the other type of media. Again, different parts are used and they can and often do fail independently.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Any recommendations for what software to use? I've tried looking into it before but I find that they're usually made for disk authoring and burning, and aren't meant for RW disks.

Comment: Any 3rd party software will do for testing purposes. And any of the dozens available can do RW. The Windows tools are a very recent development. In the heydays of optical media, i.e., many years ago, we always used 3rd party software because Windows didn't have any.